# Грамматическая основа

Tags: синтаксис

Девочку звали Алиса. Входит ли 'Алиса' в состав сказуемого?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, входит. Это составное именное сказуемое - ***звали Алиса (Алисой)***.

Comment: Спасибо. .