# Где сказуемое в предложении "Девочку звали Алиса"?

Tags: синтаксис

Где сказуемое в предложении "*Девочку звали Алиса*"?

Я думаю, что **звали Алиса**, потому что существительное в именительном падеже может быть обращением, подлежащим и сказуемым. Важно не столько, что её **звали**, а что именно **Алисой** (кстати, можно легко заменить на творительный падеж, что тоже в пользу моего варианта). Но на сайте "Решу ГИА" в ответах указан ответ **звали**.

Comment: [Повтор вопроса](http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/42100/%d0%93%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0?s=2|1.1396)

Answer (score 4):

Угу, *звали Алиса*, **составное сказуемое в предложениях именования**.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]